# The error of rails when create db on rails (rails db:create)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, bundle

When I rails db:create
after I rails new and bundle install, there is the error as the below.

**rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri**

Please teach me how to solve this error.
my situation
ruby version → 2.6.0
rails version → 6.1.2

Comment: Looks like Nokogiri is not properly installed... check whether it is installed with native extension

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get install nokogiri` to install nokogiri.